# Can I implement constants and enums with a service (Typescript Class) and an Interface?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have been using enums in Typescript like this:

```
enum Action {
    None,
    Registering,
    Authenticating
};

app.run(['$rootScope', appRun])

function appRun(
    $rootScope
    ) {
    $rootScope.Action = Action;
}
```

This works in my controllers, my services and my HTML however I am starting to find it's difficult to use as I don't know how to make an interface for an enum. Also I am wondering how sensible it is for me to be using $rootScope as I heard AngularJS 2 may not use this.

I am also using the following for constants:

```
.constant("appConstant", {
    appName: "My App",
    appVersion: 2.0,
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3048"
});
```

Is there a way that I can replace the constants and enum (enum functionality) with a class and service and interface for the service?

Comment: You can use enum in your `.d.ts` file as long as all of the values have simple integer initializers (e.g. `enum Action { None=0, Registering=1, Authenticating=2 }`). Search for term `ambient enum` if you want to find out more

Answer (score 1):

> my HTML however I am starting to find it's difficult to use as I don't know how to make an interface for an enum

Enums come with their own interfaces. Beyond that Enums are number based so number as allowed. E.g.:

```
enum Action {
    None,
    Registering,
    Authenticating
};

interface IRootScope {
    ActionValues:typeof Action
}

var $rootScope:IRootScope;
$rootScope.ActionValues = Action; 

var foo:Action = Action.None;
console.log(foo == $rootScope.ActionValues.None); // true
```